# E2e тестирование api

Tags: php, юнит-тесты

Как проверить api через phpunit 
У меня есть api http://test/testApi/apiScanTest
Она должна принимать данные

```
{
"var" : 1
}
```

Если данные коректные и данные пришли то должно принять данные и выдать ответ.
Если данные не коректные то должно выдать ошибку.
Как мне проверить данное api через phpunit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для unit-тестирования Вам хватит собственно phpunit. Напишите тесты для всех предполагаемых вариантов набора данных для каждого класса, реализующего Ваш API, и выполните их.

Для "внешнего" тестирования посредством http-запросов используйте связку phpunit+[Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/). Это уже не юнит-тесты, это функциональное тестирование. Примеров работы такой связки в нете превеликое множество. При поиске не обращайте внимание на то, что тестироваться могут API, написанные на Symfony или Laravel. В Вашем случае не важно, как и на чем написаны API, - при тестировани они все равно представляются в виде *черного ящика*. Есть запрос к API, есть его ответ. Ожидаемый ответ должен совпасть с реальным. Для начала предлагаю ознакомиться с [этой статьей](https://blog.cloudflare.com/using-guzzle-and-phpunit-for-rest-api-testing/) и [этим простым примером теста](https://gist.github.com/judges119/be4260012e40ea508cd04738d273e7c5).